# Vaadin Maven Compile Error (ComponentUtil.addListener))

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Unfortunately it is not possible to execute a maven install for my Vaadin application. I have no error in Eclipse. It is also possible to run the application via Eclipse. But the maven install runs always in this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project lunchlist: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/thomas/workspace/test/src/main/java/TestView.java:[214,42] incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[ERROR]     (argument mismatch; cannot infer functional interface descriptor for com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener<com.vaadin.flow.component.ClickEvent>)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The following code causes the compile error:

```
ComponentUtil.addListener(label, ClickEvent.class, e -> {
    xxxxx
});
```

Does anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance! :)

Best Regards,
Thomas

Comment: does your maven command use the same version of java as your eclipse is for compiling the sources of your application?

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure. How can I identify/change the java version of maven (in Eclipse)? I execute the maven command via right click in Eclipse. Regards, Thomas

Comment: I can reproduce it in IntelliJ in the sense that it shows no errors in the class, but running, building, or `mvn install` shows that error. Tried with AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11 and 1.8.0_265. You can see which version Maven uses with `mvn -version`, which should be the version pointed to by the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Java version: 15.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Same as java version for compling sources in in Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

You can get around the issue by adding an upcast to `ComponentEventListener` for your listener:

```
ComponentUtil.addListener(label, ClickEvent.class, 
    (ComponentEventListener)  e -> Notification.show("Clicked"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the error. Still the same message...

Comment: And you are adding just `(ComponentEventListener)`, not for example `(ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent>)`? For me this fixes the problem, tested with three different JDKs.

Comment: Yes, but I will get a bit other message: `[214,94] type argument com.vaadin.flow.component.ClickEvent is not within bounds of type-variable T`

Comment: In this way it works.... Thanks for your help!  

ComponentUtil.addListener(imprint, ClickEvent.class, new ComponentEventListener() {
   public void onComponentEvent(ComponentEvent event) {  xxxx }
});

Answer (score 0):

I extend a Vaadin core class and created a type specific add*Listener method that cleans up the interface types. I found this approach in the Vaadin core classes, e.g.

```
com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid.addItemClickListener(ComponentEventListener<ItemClickEvent<T>>)
```

So I added a method addClickListener to a class that extends MultiSelectListBox, which does not yet provide one:

```
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
  public Registration addClickListener(ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<?>> listener) {
    return addListener(ClickEvent.class, (ComponentEventListener) Objects.requireNonNull(listener));
  }
```

The listener method

```
private void onClick(ClickEvent<?> event) { ... }
```

can now be registered:

```
// fine in IDE (eclipse, idea); Java 8 compiler error: incompatible types:
// cannot infer functional interface descriptor for ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent>
// addListener(ClickEvent.class, this::onClick);
addClickListener(this::onClick);
```

If you do not want to extend a Vaadin class, a static helper method will do the same:

```
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
  public static Registration addComponentClickListener(Component component, ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<?>> listener) {
    return ComponentUtil.addListener(component, ClickEvent.class, (ComponentEventListener) Objects.requireNonNull(listener));
  }
```

Then you can call addComponentClickListener with any component and a listener method (e.g. this::onClick) or lambda expression like e -> { ... }.